# Arabic text in TKinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a window with text. I would like to use Arabic language in the text:

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Alram')
root.geometry("1500x600")
msg = Message(root, bg="red", text='The main interface is down, please contact your administrator')
msg.config(font=('times', 72, 'bold'))
exit_button = Button(root, width=10, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
msg.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to replace the message "*The main interface is down, please contact your administrator*" with Arabic sentence.

Any one can help please?

Comment: Did you try that? What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to set your encoding to ***UTF-8*** by making this line the first one (before your code) in your Python file: `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`

This is a code sample:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Alram')
root.geometry("1500x600")
mytext= 'ذكرت تقارير' #Arabic text
msg = Message(root, bg="red", text= mytext, justify='right')
msg.config(font=('times', 72, 'bold'))
exit_button = Button(root, width=10, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
msg.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can also change the line of `msg = ...` to `msg = Message(root, bg="red", text= 'ذكرت تقارير', justify='right')`