# Tkinter Label with arabic text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, arabic

[image: text is not okay :'(]

is there any way to make that Arabic text looks exactly how it must be :
the example below should look like "باطو"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arabic text in TKinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964605/arabic-text-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 3):

Since Arabic script is right to left, you can use the libraries: https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper and https://github.com/MeirKriheli/python-bidi

Something like this can work:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *

import arabic_reshaper

from tkinter import messagebox
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text_to_be_reshaped = "ﺏﺎﻃﻭ"
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)

bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)

top = Tk()
top.geometry("70x30")
B = Button(top, text = bidi_text)
B.place(x=0,y=0)
top.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: finally an answer that works! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer could help someone

This is how to add Arabic support to tkinter Label and Entry widgets

Edit:
This fix for Arabic on linux only,
but for Windows the bidi support will be handled by operating system and Arabic will be displayed correctly without a need for a fix.

you need to install AwesomeTkinter package `pip install awesometkinter`

example ([source](https://github.com/Aboghazala/AwesomeTkinter)):

```
import tkinter as tk
from awesometkinter.bidirender import add_bidi_support, render_text
root = tk.Tk()

text = 'السلام عليكم'

# text display incorrectly on linux without bidi support
dummyvar = tk.StringVar()
dummyvar.set(text)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=dummyvar, font='any 20').pack()

# uncomment below to set a rendered text to first label
# dummyvar.set(render_text(text))

entry = tk.Entry(root, font='any 20', justify='right')
entry.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(root, font='any 20')
lbl.pack()

# adding bidi support for widgets
add_bidi_support(lbl)
add_bidi_support(entry)

# now there is a new set() and get() methods to set and get text on a widget
entry.set(text)
lbl.set('هذا كتاب adventure شيق')

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image: example]

Note: you can write Arabic directly in entry widget normally and text flow will be correct from right to left and letters will join correctly

Comment: Arabic is by default supported for texts and not typing. Plus `entry.set()` does not exist. "_we can use set() and get() methods to set and get text on a widget"_ is partially wrong, there is no `set()` for entry widgets, and there is neither for labels.

Comment: part of the code in `atk.add_bidi_support()`  is to add set() and get() method to the widget, feel free to review the code at https://github.com/Aboghazala/AwesomeTkinter

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by [[Arabic is by default supported for texts and not typing.]] please explain more

Comment: The labels will show the Arabic text, even without any library. The only need is while typing. Oh, you directly copy pasted the contents from the GitHub :(

Comment: @CoolCloud This is not correct, tkinter has no bidi support on linux, this means Arabic letters will be shown in reversed order and not joined, but in windows the bidi support is handled by operating system and Arabic is displayed correctly, if you look at screenshot above, the first widget is a Label which display Arabic wrong, but the other widgets show Arabic correctly

Comment: Oh okay, I don't know about Linux.

Comment: @CoolCloud, yes i copied and pasted contents directly from github because I am the author of AwesomeTkinter repo, and regarding support Arabic while typing, it is working for "Entry" widget, just run the example above [[ on linux ]]  and see by yourself

Comment: I do not question your ownership. I meant by default, Arabic does not work, maybe it works using that library. Sorry for any misunderstandings :D