# Arabic text inverted in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to display Arabic text in a Tkinter program, Windows seems to display them correctly, but gets inverted in Kali Linux for some reason.

test.py file content :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

import Tkinter
import platform

root = Tk()

Label(root, text = "Python version: %s" % platform.python_version()).pack()
Label(root, text = "Tkinter version: %d" % Tkinter.TkVersion).pack()
Label(root, text = "العربية").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Result in Windows 10 Pro:

[image]

Result in Kali Linux:

[image]

Same Python and Tkinter version, but different result, anyone knows the exact reason behind this?

Comment: Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905458/tkinter-label-with-arabic-text) help?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ, the python-arabic-reshaper library, doesn't display text correctly, it has a lot of faults, try for example "هجوم". Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Newsonic it was around 2018 and no I gave up adding arabic haha

Comment: I added an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67463389/10146012 hope it help someone