# Use arabic text with tkinter

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, utf-8, arabic

I want to use Arabic language in my python app but it doesn't work. I tried the following:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
   .
   .
   .
   welcMsg = 'مرحبا'
   welcome_label = ttk.Label(header, text=welcMsg, font=(
   "KacstBook", 24)).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)
```

I also tried to add

```
   welcMsg = welcMsg.encode("windows-1256", "ignore")
```

but the result is always like this

[image]

and it also happens with tkinter Entry and Text

```
   searchField = ttk.Entry(tab3, width=50)
   textBox = Text(tab4, width=45, height=15, font=("KacstOffice", 16), selectbackground="yellow",
           selectforeground="black", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set, wrap=WORD)
```

so is there anything else I can try to work with Label, Entry and Text?

NOTE: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Comment: What OS are you using? The first code snippet works for me and displays: `مرحبا`.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Comment: The problem also effects Ubuntu 20.10 but doesn't effect Windows 10 for some reason.

Comment: I don't know if this is going to be helpful but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905458/tkinter-label-with-arabic-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't have a bidi support (According to tk's source code), which means RTL(Right-To-Left) languages like Arabic will be displayed incorrectly with 2 problems:

1- letters will be displayed in reverse order.

2- letters are not joined correctly.

the reason Arabic is being displayed correctly on windows is because bidi support is handled by operating system, and this is not the case in Linux

to fix this problem on linux you can use [AwesomeTkinter](https://github.com/Aboghazala/AwesomeTkinter) package, it can add bidi support to labels and entry (also while editing)

```
import tkinter as tk
from awesometkinter.bidirender import add_bidi_support
root = tk.Tk()

welcMsg = 'مرحبا'

# text display incorrectly on linux without bidi support
tk.Label(root, text=welcMsg).pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root, justify='right')
entry.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(root)
lbl.pack()

# adding bidi support for widgets
add_bidi_support(lbl)
add_bidi_support(entry)

# Now we have a new set() and get() methods to set and get text on a widget
# these methods added by add_bidi_support() and doesn't exist in standard widgets.
entry.set(welcMsg)
lbl.set(welcMsg)

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]

note: you can install awesometkinter by `pip install awesometkinter`

Comment: thanks for such a nice library

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to set your encoding to UTF-8 by making this line the first one (before your code) in your Python file: # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

This is a code sample:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Alram')
root.geometry("1500x600")
mytext= 'ذكرت تقارير' #Arabic text
msg = Message(root, bg="red", text= mytext, justify='right')
msg.config(font=('times', 72, 'bold'))
exit_button = Button(root, width=10, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
msg.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

here is the original answer:
[Arabic text in TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964605/arabic-text-in-tkinter)

Comment: That code doesn't solve the problem on Ubuntu 20 | Python 3.8

Comment: Actually I checked this answer before posting my question, and I don't think it's an OS problem because I can browse Arabic websites and open Arabic text files in libre without any issue

Comment: @MohabMostafa The problem effects Ubuntu 19/20 but not Windows. That is why I thought that it might be OS dependant.

Comment: Hmm, I'm searching it up, however not many sources give a good answer...

Comment: @TheLizzard not affecting MacOS too.. works well on MacOS Big Sur

Comment: On Python 3, UTF-8 encoding is the default anyway.